# reactjs not updating state when needed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, react-hooks

I have some input fields that must be set before calling `onCompleteOrder`. I store errors using `useState`, I need the program to keep looking at which fields are not set and therefore keep the error inside `errors` state. If `errors` state is not empty, then block calling that function. The problem is that the state is updated after the button is clicked, I know that this must be handled using the `useEffect` hook, how do I do that correctly?

```
const OrderModal = (props) => {

    const [errors, setErrors] = React.useState([])
    const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = React.useState(oldFile)
    const [startDate, setStartDate] = React.useState(new Date());
    const [endDate, setEndDate] = React.useState(null);
    const { isAuthenticated, user } = useAuth0();


    React.useEffect(() => {
        let currentErrors = errors.map(err => err.type)
        let newErrors = []
        if (!isAuthenticated && currentErrors.includes("authentication")) newErrors.push({ type: "authentication", message: "You must log in before creating an order!." })
        if (!selectedFile && currentErrors.includes("image")) newErrors.push({ type: "image", message: "Please select an image." })
        if (!startDate && currentErrors.includes("startDate")) newErrors.push({ type: "startDate", message: "Please select a start date." })
        if (!endDate && currentErrors.includes("endDate")) newErrors.push({ type: "endDate", message: "Please select an end date." })
        setErrors(newErrors)
    }, [isAuthenticated, selectedFile, startDate, endDate])

}

const renderInputErrors = () => {
        return (
            <>
                {errors.length > 0 &&
                    errors.map(e => {
                        return (
                            <CAlert color="danger" dismissible>
                                {e}
                            </CAlert>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </>
        )
    }

const onCompleteOrder = () => {
        if (errors.length > 0) return
        // complete the order if all fields are set. 
    }
```

Comment: I can't spot anything in your code that would trigger changing state variables, listed among dependencies for `useEffect()`

Comment: First of all you need to either include `errors` in list of `useEffect` dependencies or use the functional state update `setErrors(currentErrors => ...)`
Secondly, could you provide an [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?